# Why can I not install pulseaudio-dbgsym?

Tags: 22.04

**Why do the ddeb repos not provide a dbgsym package for my version of pulseaudio?  Does anybody know?**

My version of pulseaudio is:

```
1:15.99.1+dfsg1-1ubuntu2.1 (jammy-updates)
```

There is only a dbgsym package for an older version:

```
1:15.99.1+dfsg1-1ubuntu1 (jammy)
```

I tried to use the instructions on the [Debug Symbol Packages](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Debug%20Symbol%20Packages) page, on the Ubuntu Wiki.

dbgsym packages are available for many other packages, including package versions from jammy-updates.

Launchpad says [the dbgsym package has been built](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pulseaudio/1:15.99.1+dfsg1-1ubuntu2.1/+build/25641237), so why is it not published in the ddeb repos?

### Error messages

```
$ # ddeb repos below installed as per https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Debug%20Symbol%20Packages
$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ddebs.list
deb http://ddebs.ubuntu.com jammy main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://ddebs.ubuntu.com jammy-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://ddebs.ubuntu.com jammy-proposed main restricted universe multiverse

$ sudo apt -qq install pulseaudio-dbg
E: Unable to locate package pulseaudio-dbg

$ sudo apt -qq install pulseaudio-dbgsym
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 pulseaudio-dbgsym : Depends: pulseaudio (= 1:15.99.1+dfsg1-1ubuntu1)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

### Use case

I wished to install debug symbols to use with `perf record`.  `perf record --debuginfod` does not work, it says "debuginfod support requested, but perf is not built with it".

I wished to use `perf` on pulseaudio, because I saw pulseaudio using ~10% CPU for at least a minute, despite not playing or recording audio.  (Of course now I go to look at it again, it has stopped doing that :-).

If pulseaudio was using 100% CPU, I guess I could just try `gdb` with `debuginfod`, collect a few samples very manually, and guess where the hot spot is.  But at ~10% CPU, I guess I would need to collect several times more samples, because many of the samples will be when pulseaudio is idle and not actually using CPU :-).